# Simple Form Select with Rails Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I realise most questions relating to using Simple Form (of this nature at least) go unanswered. I'm really struggling to understand the basics. The documentation is premised on too much knowledge for me to figure it out.

This is the overview from the simple form documentation that I'm trying to understand. A worked example would really help me to learn.

```
#attribute_name, #column, #html_classes, #input_html_classes, #input_html_options, #input_type, #options, #reflection
```

I'd really appreciate some help with using select options in Simple Form.

Below is the extract from the Simple Form overview.

```
f.input :age, collection: 18..60, prompt: "Select your age"
```

I'm trying to use that as an example (along with the country priorities shown in the Simple Form overview example) to make the options between the elements in my array work. Can anyone see what I've done wrong. My attempt below (and many others) have not worked. I'm stuck.

```
<div class="question-project">
  <%= f.input :expense_type, collection: [Incidental, Less than $500, More than $500 ], prompt: "Are the expenses:"%></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Also check this out: https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap, an example application with Simple Form and Twitter Bootstrap 2 & 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array needs to have strings, like so:

`<%= f.input :expense_type, collection: ["Incidental", "Less than $500", "More than $500" ], prompt: "Are the expenses:"%></div>`

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. I should have been able to get that one... Thank you

Comment: It's a common error. Always ask yourself - is this word defined somewhere? I.e. is it a variable? If not then it should be a string.